# Compilation error in the process of installing fast-rcnn

Tags: caffe

```
src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu(142): error: argument of type "double *" is incompatible with parameter of type "size_t" detected during instantiation of "void caffe::CuDNNConvolutionLayer::Backward_gpu(const std::vector *, std::allocator *>> &, const std::vector<__nv_bool, std::allocator<__nv_bool>> &, const std::vector *, std::allocator *>> &) [with Dtype=double]" (159): here
src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu(142): error: too few arguments in function call detected during instantiation of "void caffe::CuDNNConvolutionLayer::Backward_gpu(const std::vector *, std::allocator *>> &, const std::vector<__nv_bool, std::allocator<__nv_bool>> &, const std::vector *, std::allocator *>> &) [with Dtype=double]" (159): here
20 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001284_00000000-16_cudnn_conv_layer.compute_50.cpp1.ii". make: * [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.o] Error 1 make: * Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following [these](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn) instructions on Rob's site for installing fast rcnn.

Also you could check to see if the issue is with your cudnn config by following [these](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Install-Caffe-on-EC2-from-scratch-(Ubuntu,-CUDA-7,-cuDNN)) instructions (assuming you're using EC2 or Ubuntu 14.04).

If its still an issue, would be helpful if you could share the steps you took which give you this error and what machine OS you're building to.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this trouble recently. It occurs when I compile the project of [fast-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn), but doesn't occur for [py-faster-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) and [enter link description here](https://github.com/ShaoqingRen/faster_rcnn). After I read the caffe installation guide which is presented on web: [Caffe Installation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html), I think the version of cuDNN(the former is v3, the latter is v4) may result in the problem. My installation version of cuDNN is v4.0.7, and it runs well for the latter two projects.